# Convert the object into a string and bring in the necessary form

Tags: node.js

An object comes to me. I write the variable key and the value through the loop:

```
 let update_info = [];
 for (let[key, value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
    update_info.push(`${key} = ${value}`);
 }
 console.log(JSON.parse(update_info));
```

Output to console:

```
undefined:1
user_name = name,user_email = @email.com,user_password = 12345678,about = aboutaboutaboutabout
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

Why it happens?

I need to be displayed in the console like this:

```
'user_name' = 'name','user_email' = '@email.com','user_password' = '12345678','about' = 'aboutaboutaboutabout
```

How do i implement this?

Comment: `update_info` is an *array*, so trying to `JSON.parse` it doesn't make any sense. Only try to `JSON.parse` JSON strings. Just do `console.log(update_info)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced your code like this and all you need to do is

**JSON.stringify** turns a JavaScript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

**JSON.parse** turns a string of JSON text into a JavaScript object.

```js
 let obj = {
    "welcome": "hello",
    "reply": "hi"
 }
 let update_info = [];
 for (let[key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    update_info.push(`${key} = ${value}`);
 }
 console.log(JSON.stringify(update_info));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

You need not to parse it using `JSON.parse` because the array is not yet stringified, so you should use `toString()` to achieve the desired result

```
 let update_info = [];
 for (let[key, value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
    update_info.push(`'${key}' = '${value}'`);
 }
 console.log(update_info.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in printing the Object key value pair in the console to have better view use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object, undefined, 2))
```

This will print the object in proper format indented by 2 spaces